# Error usando recursividad para obtener los divisores de un numero

Tags: java

Hola estoy intentando hallar los divisores de un numero perdido entre 0 y ese número pero no logro entender bien la recursividad.
Solo consigo que me imprima todos los numeros desde 0 hasta ese número?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Escribe un número");
    int numero = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

    busquedaRecursiva(0,numero);

}

public static void busquedaRecursiva(int cont, int numParada) {


    if (cont >= numParada) {//caso base
        System.out.print(cont + " ");
    }else if (cont % numParada  ==0 ){
         //Equivalente al ámbito del for
         System.out.println( numParada+" es multiplo de "  );
          //Equivalente a i+i
         busquedaRecursiva(cont+1,numParada);
    }
}
```

Comment: Primer error los print nunca van en un metodo solo en el main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prueba con:

```
public static void busquedaRecursiva(int cont, int numParada) {

    if(cont != 0 && numParada % cont  == 0)
        System.out.printf("%d es múltiplo de %d . " ,numParada, cont);

    if(cont < numParada)
        busquedaRecursiva(cont+1,numParada);
}
```

Debería funcionar con números negativos también.

Comment: Nunca he usado printf, si lo cambio a println me da error?

Comment: Puedes leer [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) de la documentación oficial de Java para que entiendas un poco su uso. Eso no implica que no puedas usar `println`. Saludos